# Howto install w/o root priviliges

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

We are in an infrastructure where a large number of machines runs an Ubuntu from Netboot (University). We would like to install ROS into a common prefix that will be shared to all machines via NFS. We do not have root on these machines, therefore we would like to be able to build ROS completely from source!! There must be a way, right?! E.g. using cmake/pkg-config to find packages instead of apt...

Has anyone done this?!

Any help will be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44030/howto-install-w/o-root-priviliges/) by [Das_rote_Skelett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2753/das_rote_skelett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, ROS has been designed from the start to be build from sources by the community. The apt way was added later for convenience.

The details change between ROS distributions, so check the instructions for the distribution you intend to use.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Das_rote_Skelett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2753/das_rote_skelett/) on 2012-09-18**:
Well, it starts off with:  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'. And does a lot of "sudos" later on. We *DO NOT* have root nor will our admins allow us to add an alternative repository location for security reasons...

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-24**:
You will need to install any system dependencies into a local location and add it to your path.  Then you can use ROS from source.